# How to redirect a user to a login page if they are not logged in? Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm fairly new to the whole Swift thing, but I'm trying to make a simple login screen where if the user is not logged in, it redirects them to a login page. I seem to have something not write in the code as when I click on the tab to take me to the login page as I'm not logged in nothing comes Up? When I type in the code, Xcode says everything is fine but I've named the root loginView and everything seems to be alright, but when I load it nothing happens it just come up with the page as If you were logged in.

Any ideas?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginView", sender: self);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

As you do not get any errors I believe you've correctly named your segue right? if that's the case. Please make sure you're doing as following:

Let's assume you have 2 View Controllers one is the main page that logged in users can go (we name it LandingVC) and the other one is the login view controller (we call it LoginVC).

First thing to check: make sure you're writing the code in LandingVC ? 
Second: Have you assigned the class to VCs in StoryBoard? (see picture for reference)

[image: Select View Controller Class Correctly]